# Next 14 Error on Vercel Deployment - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, nextjs-dynamic-routing, vercel-middleware

My project is running completely fine on localhost but when I deploy it on the vercel server it shows me this error : [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jb4Q.png) I don't know how to fix this error. I even checked the server logs there it shows task time after 10.00s. [Server Logs of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5E4J.png).
It is showing error while fetching data from '/api/profile' route and '/api/taskslist' route. But both of them are working fine on the local host and I don't see any issue of why it is getting the timeout here.

Just for the refference I am giving the code of both api routes as well.
**'/api/profile' route :**

```
import user from "@/models/user";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request | NextRequest) {
  try {
    const auth = cookies().get("userToken") || "";
    if (!auth) {
      return new Response("Unauthorized", {
        status: 401,
      });
    }

    const { id } = jwt.verify(auth.value, process.env.JWT_SECRET!) as any;

    const userExist = await user.findOne({ _id: id });

    if (!userExist) {
      return new Response("User not found", {
        status: 401,
      });
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(userExist), {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Unauthorized", {
      status: 401,
    });
  }
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

**'/api/tasklist' route :**

```
import userTasks from "@/models/userTasks";
import { extractTokenPayload } from "@/utils/functions";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request | NextRequest) {
  try {
    const auth = cookies().get("userToken") || ("" as any);
    if (!auth) {
      return new Response("Unauthorized", {
        status: 401,
      });
    }

    const userId = await extractTokenPayload(auth);

    const taskList = await userTasks.find({ user_id: userId });
    // console.log(userId, taskList);

    if (!taskList) {
      return new Response("Tasks with this user id not found", {
        status: 401,
      });
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(taskList), {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Unauthorized", {
      status: 401,
    });
  }
}

export async function DELETE(req: Request | NextRequest) {
  try {
    const urlParams = new URL(req.url!);
    const taskId = urlParams.searchParams.get("id");

    if (!taskId) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Task ID is required" }), {
        status: 400,
      });
    }

    const task = await userTasks.findOne({ _id: taskId });
    if (!task) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Task not found" }), {
        status: 404,
      });
    }

    const deletedTask = await userTasks.deleteOne({ _id: taskId });

    if (deletedTask) {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ message: "Task deleted successfully" }),
        {
          status: 200,
        }
      );
    } else {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ message: "Unexpected error. Please try again." }),
        { status: 500 }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue ? or like where is the main problem causing these errors.

I tried adding this "
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";" to remove the dynamic server I am getting during build. It solved the dynamic server error but the main problem is not solved.